# list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, массивы, split

Как лечить это?

```
    disk = session.get(controler_1, verify=False)
    print(disk)
    disk_t = json.loads(disk1.text)
    print(disk_t)
    cont = disk_t['data']['CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_LIST']
    print(cont)
    data = controler_read_write_1.split(',')
```

У меня вылетает такая ошибка:

```
cont = disk_t['data']['CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_LIST']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Вы смогли перевести и понять текст ошибки?

Comment: Да это понятно что должно быть цифры, у меня там внутри идет 56,56,56,33 , я не знаю как перевести это все в int, пробовал ставить cont = int(disk_t['data']['CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_LIST']) не помогает)

Comment: @user405396 где внутри? У вас индекс `'data'`, а это строка

Comment: @dIm0n , в ['CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_LIST'] , и как мне быть? Не понимаю

Comment: Покажите полностью, что у вас выводит print(disk_t) Как по вашему мы должны вам помочь, если мы не видим ваши данные?

Comment: @user405396 не использовать строки, вестимо

Comment: @Xander {
    "data": [
        {
            "CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_ID_LIST": "23,26,25,28",
            "CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_LIST": "17,75,408,4628",
            "CMO_STATISTIC_TIMESTAMP": "1600245928",
            "CMO_STATISTIC_UUID": "216:1"
        }
    ],
    "error": {
        "code": 0,
        "description": "0"
    }
}

Comment: `disk_t['data'][0]['CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_LIST']`. Квадратные скобки внутри ведь не просто так.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Поясните почему через [0] , у меня же там нету 0 , data - CMO_STATISTIC_DATA_ID_LIST - значение

Comment: [0] это не 0, а первый элемент списка.

Comment: `'data'` - ключ, значение: `[<что-то внутри>]` - список. А точнее: `[{ <что-то внутри> }]` - список с одним словарём внутри.